# '\0' в конце строки, так ли он нужен?

Tags: c++, c, строки, память

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main()
{
    char* src = strdup("Hello!");
    int len = strlen(src);
    char* dest = (char*) malloc(len);
    memcpy(dest, src, len);
    int len2 = strlen(dest);
    printf("Destination: %s %d\nSource: %s\n", dest,len2, src);
    printf("Source: %s", src);
    do
    {
        printf("-- %c\n", *dest);
    }while(*dest++ != '\0');
    return 0;    
}
```

Как вы можете заметить в memcpy я не копирую '\0' но тем не менее цикл while не бесконечный и выводит всю строку без мусора. Так  вот, есть ли в этом коде ошибка, должен ли я добавлять '\0' к скопированной строке? Есть ли ситуации когда добавлять '\0' не обязательно? Я хочу понять, либо строка так в памяти удачно раполагается, что '\0' за пределами строки лежит, либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо компилятор очень умный. Объясните, почему я не получаю бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Этому должно быть логичное объяснение. Чудес не бывает.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Понимаете, у вас сейчас получился примерно следующий рассказ.

Мне всю жизнь говорят, что переходить на красный свет нельзя. Но посмотрите - я перешел на красный. Затем перебежал на красный. Затем даже переполз - и ничего! Я жив, я не в больнице!

Так, может переходить дорогу на зеленый - не обязательно?

У вас *в любом случае* наблюдается выход за границы выделенной памяти - нулевой символ уже *за пределами* выделенной `malloc` памяти, а значит, это undefined behavior и говорить больше не о чем. Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное...

Answer (score -3):

"\0" устанавливается автоматически при создании строки символов. Вы всё сделали правильно. В memcpy  вы копируете длину строки - это равнозначно установлению квадратных скобок при объявлении и инициализации. Равнозначно можно было указать sizeof(). Вот отсутствие того или другого вызвало бы негодование компилятора. Никаких дополнительных действий больше не требуется. В вашем случае он как и был прописан в 8 байте. В случае посимвольного ввода getchar() для сохранения в строку потребовалось бы самостоятельно устанавливать"\0".

Comment: И все же, автор делает неправильно. Он пишет `int len = strlen(src); ... memcpy(dest, src, len);`. Таким образом, завершающий строку `src` ноль не копируется. Соответствующий байт в `dst` не меняется (нет гарантии, что там будет ноль). Это ошибка.

Comment: "\0" на месте. Это легко проверить. Да и while тому свидетель.

Comment: Ну, смотрите. `src = "ab";`  -- Тут 2 байта данных -- `a` и `b`, после которых идет 0. `strlen(src)` очевидно равен 2. Тогда получим `memcpy(dst, src. 2);`, **видите 2?**. Следовательно, 0 не копируется. Можете проверить, например, заполнив перед копированием dst -- например, `strcpy(dst, "123");` и распечатать его после копирования *(только не забудьте перед экспериментом выделить под dst достаточно памяти)**

Comment: В приведённом вами примере с числом 2, "\0" автоматически устанавливается в 3 байт. Это свойство функции прописанное в заголовочном файле. Так же как и например при инициализации строки мы не заботимся о установке "\0". Это происходит автоматически. Поменяйте переменную len в memcpy() на любое число в итоге всегда будет len+1.

Comment: *`"Поменяйте переменную len в memcpy() на любое число в итоге всегда будет len+1."`* -- это не верно. Читайте [man memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html), она копирует ровно столько байт, сколько заказано

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ee7xqTTGj

Comment: Наверное мне больше нечего добавить к сказанному. Нуль символ в данном примере всегда len+1. Это просто неоспоримый факт.

Comment: Видимо троллите? Я же скинул пример, где `\0` не добавляется...

Comment: Нет, не троллю. Слишком долго приводить примеры когда одни и те же функции в различных обстоятельствах ведут себя по разному. Дискуссия зашла в тупик.